# Should I Encrypt Information in transit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, https

I am building an asp.net core MVC website. where I Deal with sensitive data.

For example, the Teacher has some students studying under their guidance.
they can retrieve student's personal information. so I have the page for displaying Student Info.
when I pass student info from server to client should I encrypt personal information during transfer??

because we always encrypt passwords even if we are on https and form has POST request

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see the help center to create a minimally reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .  Unfortunately, we don't write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HTTPS, you're fine because the browser takes care of encryption for you. Just make sure that you do use HTTPS.